Word Add in not showing up in Word
I made an add-in by myself using visual C# and the run-time VSTO plugin. I can install and run it on my computer which has Office 2021 Professional Plus. The problem comes on a different computer, the add-in installs and shows up in Control Panel as an installed program but it refuses to show up in word. The second computer has Office 2019 Home and Business. Both are on windows. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
I thought it might have been the certificates, but I got that working and it installs on the second machine. But it doesn't show up. In the publishing tab I have two Prerequisites selected: "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.2 (x86 and x64)" and "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)".
I also tried to see if there are maybe some settings which I am missing but I could see a difference between the two Office's.

Does Word show it in File | Options | Addins?

Nope, but I did add it using File | Options | Add-ins | COM Add-ins | Go | Add. It still refused to show up.

Is there an entry for your addin in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins? Or in HKLM?

Have you checked  File | Options | Add-ins | Disabled Items? If it's disabled it will not activate though File | Options | Add-ins | COM Add-ins.
